# Skip debug instructions (and their content) if logging is set to INFO

Tags: python, logging

I have a program in which I wrote logs both as info and debug.

Since the debug contains also calls to slow functions, my program is running slow even if I set debugging to INFO.

Is it possible to completely skip those line from computation?

in the next example 10 seconds have to pass before the info log is executed.

```
import logging.handlers
import sys
import time

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging_stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
logging_stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s --- %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(logging_stream_handler)

logger.debug("aaa", time.sleep(10))
logger.debug("bbb")
logger.info("ccc")
```

Comment: You shouldn't have logic in logging!

Comment: logger.debug("degree: %s", graph.degree(current_edge[direction]))

Comment: Either you need the degree -> you should have it in your normal logic. Or you don't -> it's not relevant to the debug statement/function.

Comment: @iScrE4m. I don't agree with that. Debug is to better analyze something maybe from a proprammer point of view, and if I need to run a function that execute a deep analysis (not normally necessary), where is the problem? I think the solution proposed to put "if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):" to branch log is fine

Comment: Your logic should be split to simple functions so that you can just track stuff specific to that function and making sure it works fine. If something is not calculated during the whole function and you want to calculate it just for debug... Maybe you need it, I don't know enough about your work, but it seems odd.

Comment: The solution works and it's nice and easy one - just make sure that you actually need it is all I'm saying.

Comment: It is just because I have a lot debugging already in place that execute a lot of long running sage function (is_planar, is_regular, ...). I was in need of a fast method to skip processing on those debugging lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the logger is enabled for such a level with the [`isEnabledFor`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.isEnabledFor) method:

```
if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
    logger.debug("aaa", time.sleep(10))
    logger.debug("bbb")
```

Comment: I did this, thanks to all "logger.debug" lines.

if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG): logger.debug("aaa", time.sleep(10))

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have logging inside debug commands. If you must, then in order to skip it you must branch your code.

```
import logging.handlers
import sys
import time

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging_stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
logging_stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s --- %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(logging_stream_handler)

if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
    logger.debug("aaa", time.sleep(10))
    logger.debug("bbb")
logger.info("ccc")
```